# Link attribute data-direction="reverse" doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I made the following link, but the transition doesn't work as expected any more. It did work before.

```
<a data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" href="/home" class="ui-btn-text ui-btn-inline btn-back" title="Home"><span class="pe-7s-home"></span></a>
```

The below button works correctly.

```
<a data-rel="back" data-direction="reverse" href="#" class="ui-btn-text ui-btn-inline btn-back" title="Go back"><span class="pe-7s-angle-left"></span></a>
```

- jQuery v1.11.3.
- jQuery Mobile 1.4.5

Comment: Should the `href="/home"` be `href="#home"`?